# Migrate back to angular 7

Tags: angular, npm, angular7, angular8

How can I migrate back to angular 7 from angular 8?

I saved branch that is in angular 7 but after I did npm I on angular 8 branch- every build i get a lot of error.

I try to do `npm i` again on anguar 7 branch - but I didn't help...
[image: My error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get back to angular 7 branch, then delete node_modules folder,

Then activate

```
npm i
```

And it back to angular 7 again..